# Admob Rewarded Video: Displays in Xcode Simulator but not actual iPhone

Tags: ios, objective-c, admob

I've been searching for hours for what is probably a very simple fix. I am trying to display AdMob rewarded videos, not mediated, just admob network videos.

My videos play perfectly and reward the user perfectly in any Xcode simulator. However, when I run the app on my iPhone, I get this error in the console:

> Cannot find an ad network adapter with the name(s): com.google.DummyAdapter. Remember to link all required ad network adapters and SDKs, and set -ObjC in the 'Other Linker Flags' setting of your build target.

I will add all my code here. Please let me know if you have any ideas!

```
-(IBAction)playRewardedVideo:(id)sender{
    //If the ad is loaded, play the ad
    if ([[GADRewardBasedVideoAd sharedInstance] isReady]) {
        [[GADRewardBasedVideoAd sharedInstance] presentFromRootViewController:self];
    } else {
        //if the ad is not loaded, load an AdMob rewarded video
        [GADRewardBasedVideoAd sharedInstance].delegate = self;
        [[GADRewardBasedVideoAd sharedInstance] loadRequest:[GADRequest request]
                                               withAdUnitID:@"My_AppUnitID_Here"];
    }
}
-(void)viewDidLoad{

    //preload an AdMob rewarded video upon View loading
    [GADRewardBasedVideoAd sharedInstance].delegate = self;
    [[GADRewardBasedVideoAd sharedInstance] loadRequest:[GADRequest request]
                                           withAdUnitID:@"My_AppUnitID_Here"];
}





- (void)rewardBasedVideoAd:(GADRewardBasedVideoAd *)rewardBasedVideoAd
//reward user for completing an AdMob RV
   didRewardUserWithReward:(GADAdReward *)reward {
    NSString *rewardMessage =
    [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Reward received with currency %@ , amount %lf",
     reward.type,
     [reward.amount doubleValue]];
    NSLog(rewardMessage);

    totalCoins = totalCoins + [reward.amount doubleValue];
    [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setInteger:totalCoins forKey:@"SaveCoins"];

}

//Everything below is just NSLogs    
    - (void)rewardBasedVideoAdDidReceiveAd:(GADRewardBasedVideoAd *)rewardBasedVideoAd {
        NSLog(@"Reward based video ad is received.");
    }

- (void)rewardBasedVideoAdDidOpen:(GADRewardBasedVideoAd *)rewardBasedVideoAd {
    NSLog(@"Opened reward based video ad.");
}

- (void)rewardBasedVideoAdDidStartPlaying:(GADRewardBasedVideoAd *)rewardBasedVideoAd {
    NSLog(@"Reward based video ad started playing.");
}

- (void)rewardBasedVideoAdDidClose:(GADRewardBasedVideoAd *)rewardBasedVideoAd {
    NSLog(@"Reward based video ad is closed.");
}

- (void)rewardBasedVideoAdWillLeaveApplication:(GADRewardBasedVideoAd *)rewardBasedVideoAd {
    NSLog(@"Reward based video ad will leave application.");
}

- (void)rewardBasedVideoAd:(GADRewardBasedVideoAd *)rewardBasedVideoAd
    didFailToLoadWithError:(NSError *)error {
    NSLog(@"Reward based video ad failed to load.");

}
```

Comment: And yes, I have the -ObjC added in linker flags

Comment: check this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31948682/ios-app-from-admob-error-com-google-dummyadapter/34366737#34366737

Comment: @Jigar I read that post but why would AdMob have inventory for the simulator and not my iPhone? I also do not have a floor set

Comment: Hi @LodgeApps did you find any solution?

Comment: @LucianoRodríguez Never ended up finding a solution to this... Let me know if you do!

Answer (score 5):

I had the same issue:
video plays perfectly on simulators and iPad, no way to display them in my iPhone.

What solved it for me was going under the iPhone **Settings > Privacy > Advertising**  and turn off **Limit Ad Tracking**.

**⚠️ Note:** The Limit Ad Tracking setting for me was turned off already! I had to turn it ON and back OFF again to take effect.