# Admob ads banner not showing on iOS

Tags: ios, swift, admob, ads

I managed to successfully implement admob banner ad for my app which was published on the appstore. The ads have been showing for about a week. Suddenly 2 days ago - ads stopped showing on my app. I received a message on my dashboard indicating that "some apps haven't been configured to use apples SKADNetwork" - I thought maybe this was my issue so i followed the link https://developers.google.com/admob/ios/ios14?hl=en-GB

I followed this link to add the relevant values to my info.plist. However this did not fix the issue. I also tried to ad the test banner to see if this would show, but also test banner doesn't show. Instead when i add test banner app id i get this error:

Error Domain=com.google.admob Code=8 "Cannot find an ad network adapter with the name(s): com.google.DummyAdapter. Remember to link all required ad network adapters and SDKs, and set -ObjC in the 'Other Linker Flags' setting of your build target." UserInfo={NSLocalizedDescription=Cannot find an ad network adapter with the name(s): com.google.DummyAdapter. Remember to link all required ad network adapters and SDKs, and set -ObjC in the 'Other Linker Flags' setting of your build target., gad_response_info=  ** Response Info **

any help would be appreciated!

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31948682/ios-app-from-admob-error-com-google-dummyadapter help?